# Combine profile picture and title with css alignment

Tags: html, image, css, alignment, tumblr

I am trying to combine a profile picture with text (title) on my [**tumblr theme**](http://sindreolsson.tumblr.com).

**I have problems with the alignment.** I also need it to be good in responsive view. (If title gets to big, it should fall under - [**made a picture to illustrate**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Ft0.png).

**css**

```
#header .user-portrait {
border-radius: 100%;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin-right: 18px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
}

#header a {
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 34px;
vertical-align: top;
}

#description {
color: {color:Description};
padding-right: {text:Minus width for header in px}px;
}

#page-masthead ul { 
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
clear: both;
line-height: 1.92em;
padding-right: {text:Minus width for header in px}px;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="page-masthead">
<div id="header">

<a href="/"><img src="{PortraitURL-40}" alt="" class="user-portrait"></a>

{block:IfShowblogtitle}
<a href="/">{Title}</a>
{/block:IfShowblogtitle}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for you media queries. SO isn't a place to get code written for you.

Comment: @mikedidthis Sorry for making my qs unclear. Picture I made to illustrate shows what alignment I want for normal and if the title needs to colapse. Right now the text and image becomes to different lines if it needs to colapse. Text/title should look more aligned in middle of avatar.

Comment: Again, please show the complete code. At the moment the question lacks minimal understanding of CSS.

Comment: @mikedidthis I have added html code and where I have put it. I do not have more code when it comes to this profile picture and it surroundings.

Comment: you want it to be responsive, but have zero media queries? Please try.

Comment: I understand howto make it responsive, and how to adjust with media queries. My point is that I need to connect avatar with title. Looks like they have got it to work pretty well here. http://debut-theme.tumblr.com/. Title and avatar needs to be aligned better then it is now. I can adjust is myself with media queries if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is when the width is small enough use a media query as follows;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ??px) {

    #header .user-portrait {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto /* To center the "span" or whatever you're using */
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats what "Responsive" is, if your site is fully "responsive" then it should work in "every size"